# For loop returns undefined variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var formobj = document.h1;
for (var j = 0; j < formobj.elements.length; j++) {
    if (formobj.elements[j].type == "radiobutton" && formobj.elements[j].checked) {
        var wholebase = formobj.elements[j].value;
    }
}
```

Later in the script, the variable is set to the inner html of a div and is labeled as undefined. Is there a flaw in my for loop?

Comment: Which variable is "the variable"?

Comment: @JesusSqueegee Shouldn't it be 'radio' instead of 'radiobutton'?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Indeed it should.

Comment: The only possible flaw is that you never get inside the inner for, which is not a flaw but means that you are looking for something which is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no type `radiobutton`, I think you want `type == 'radio'`.

Answer (score -1):

Your `wholesale` variable is defined within the inner scope. Once you leave this scope the variable no longer exists. Read about Javascript scope [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) or [here](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/).
You can change your code like this:

```
var wholebase = null; //<-- declare the variable here
var formobj = document.h1;   
for (var j = 0; j < formobj.elements.length; j++){
        if (formobj.elements[j].type == "radiobutton" && formobj.elements[j].checked){
        wholebase = formobj.elements[j].value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ilia Frenkel Actually, this is wrong.  Javascript the Good Parts: "Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have block scope even though its block syntax suggests that it does. This confusion can be a source of errors." Try a simple test case where you declare some variable in a for loop then use it in the line after the loop closes.  It will be visible.

Comment: @AlexMA You are absolutely right! That's what happens when you code in 4 different languages before lunch break :-)